# cellEdited not triggering in version 5.0.7

Tags: tabulator

I can't get `cellEdited` to trigger in version 5.0 or greater - it did in 4.9 and does not work in v5.+

I read through the upgrade docs, but didn't see anything that might have changed for this feature.

Here is a small example of what worked before but no longer works.

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.0.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob"
  }, ];

  //Build Tabulator
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "311px",
    columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      width: 150,
      editor: "input",
      cellEdited: (cell) => (console.log('edited'))
    }, ],
    data: tabledata
  });
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with V5.0, most callbacks have now been replaced with events. Try using:

```js
table.on('cellEdited', () => {
  //do something
})
```

Here is an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.0.7/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@5.0/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="example-table"></div>
</body>
<script>
  var tabledata = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Oli Bob"
  }, ];

  //Build Tabulator
  var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    height: "311px",
    columns: [{
      title: "Name",
      field: "name",
      width: 150,
      editor: "input"
    }],
    data: tabledata
  });

  table.on('cellEdited', (cell) => {
    console.log('edited')
  })
</script>

</html>
```